# How to remove/avoid prepended tablename in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

GBQ prepends the table name on a join:

```
SELECT *
FROM dataset.table1 a
JOIN dataset.table2 b
  ON a.key_a = b.key_b
```

Will produce a table with fields named `a_field_1, a_field_2, ..., b_field_a`.

Is there a way to query tables without prepending the table names to the fields in the resulting table?

I want a final table with fields named `field_1, field_2, field_a (with the assumption that a and b don't have fieldnames that are identical).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BigQuery Standard SQL (see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)) where tables' aliases are not prepended so you can run your query as is and get expected result.

In BigQuery Legacy SQL you can use achieve this by explicitly listing fields to be in output

```
SELECT key_a, key_b, field_1, field_2, field_a
FROM dataset.table1 a
JOIN dataset.table2 b
  ON a.key_a = b.key_b
```