# Is there a way to prepend joined tablename in BigQuery Standard SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to know if it is possible to force standard SQL to prepend joined tablenames, so that I can get all fields from a and b with a_ and b_ prepended, without manually naming each field.  Ie. I want to do a `SELECT *`, I don't want to generate each fieldname.

I know that if you switch from Legacy SQL to Standard SQL, a

```
SELECT *
FROM first_table a
JOIN second_table b
ON a.key = b.key
```

won't automatically prepend the a_ and b_ to each outputted variable, as described in this question: [How to remove/avoid prepended tablename in bigquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040524/how-to-remove-avoid-prepended-tablename-in-bigquery)  But I want to know if that behavior can be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option is to "separate" the names by using a dot, i.e. returning a struct with the columns from each side:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM first_table a
JOIN second_table b
ON a.key = b.key;
```

If you only want certain columns from each table, you can use subselects:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM (SELECT x, y, key FROM first_table) a
JOIN (SELECT foo, bar, key FROM second_table) b
ON a.key = b.key;
```

Comment: Thanks- could you please see my related question on flattening structs in standard sql?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865903/how-to-flatten-a-struct-in-bigquery-standard-sql

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little generic - so my answer have chance to not to address PO's specific practical needs, but I thought it would be interesting to consider below approach in some cases

Idea is to have table (template table - it can be just empty) with needed columns names and than use it as first table in union all with your real query

Something like this:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM template WHERE NULL UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM first_table AS a
JOIN second_table AS b 
ON a.key = b.key
```

You can try/test this approach with below dummy tables

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH first_table AS (
  SELECT 777 AS key, 1 AS x, 2 AS y, 3 AS z
),
second_table  AS (
  SELECT 777 AS key, 4 AS x, 5 AS y, 6 AS z
),
template AS (
  SELECT NULL AS a_key, NULL AS a_x, NULL AS a_y, NULL AS a_z, NULL AS b_key, NULL AS b_x, NULL AS b_y, NULL AS b_z
)
SELECT * FROM template WHERE NULL UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM first_table AS a
JOIN second_table AS b 
ON a.key = b.key
```

with result as below

```sql
a_key   a_x a_y a_z b_key   b_x b_y b_z  
777     1   2   3   777     4   5   6
```

Comment: In this example, you have to provide the template table with all variables defined.  Following the accepted answer, you could also do: ```WITH first_table AS (
  SELECT 777 AS key, 1 AS x, 2 AS y, 3 AS z
),
second_table  AS (
  SELECT 777 AS key, 4 AS x, 5 AS y, 6 AS z
)
SELECT a, b
FROM first_table AS a
JOIN second_table AS b 
ON a.key = b.key```  This provides results from both tables, but instead of an underscore, a period separates the table name from the field.  Hope that is useful!

Comment: yes, template should be defined such that it represents the final schema and column naming you expect to have. so not the perfect option - but gives exactly what you asked :) Hope that is useful and deserves vote up :o)